# How to convert datediff & curdate() from MySql to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL query which works fine in MySQL:

`SELECT     floor(datediff(u.created_at, curdate()) / 1) AS days_ago`

I'm working to convert this from MySQL to PostgreSQL but have so far failed... Here is what I have so far:

`SELECT     floor(DATEDIFF(u.created_at, NOW()) / 1) AS days_ago`

This is erroring with:

```
ERROR:  function datediff(timestamp without time zone, timestamp with time zone) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  floor(DATEDIFF(u.created_at, NOW()) / 1) AS days_ago...
```

How can I get this query working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your version will generate a negative number.  Is that what you intend?

In any case, in Postgres, you can just take the difference of two dates:

```
SELECT (u.created_at::date - current_date) as days_ago
```

Comment: thanks for this... If I wanted this to be weeks_ago, in MySql I was able to do: `floor(datediff(u.created_at, curdate()) / 7) AS weeks_ago` --- If I try that with your suggestion in PostgreSQL it errors: I tried `SELECT (u.created_at::date - current_date / 7) as weeks_ago`

Comment: Is there a way to get your suggestion to work for days_ago and weeks_ago?

Comment: @AnApprentice . . . Just divide by 7 for weeks.